# Find the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the expression $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots (x+400)$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, contest-math, problem-solving, binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the expression $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots (x+400)$

I have no clue how to start. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: after distribution, the coefficient of x^19 must be the sum of all possibilities that have 19 x's and 400-19=381 numbers, ie, your answer is the sum of the all possible products of 381 numbers between 1 and 400

Comment: Is that easy to found? All possible products of 381 numbers between 1 and 400?

Comment: hmm no idea. But I'm sure that it's impossible by hand

Comment: There maybe is some trick due to the fact that 1,...,400 are consecutive integers.

Comment: The [tag:contest-math] tag seems to imply that this can be done by hand, but as Andrew pointed out in his answer, the result is greater than $\binom{400}{19}381!\approx5\cdot10^{851}$, so even if there were a nice trick to calculate it it could hardly be calculated by hand. It would be useful if you could provide the source of this problem and the basis of your apparent belief that there is a solution more efficient than the obvious one and that it is a suitable contest problem.

Comment: Maybe an expression for how to calculate it would be enough for an answer. It's not really given in the question what kind of an answer would be acceptable.

Comment: @joriki You can still give an answer by hand even if it is not fully simplified. For example, saying the constant term is $400!$ would probably be an acceptable answer if that was what was being asked.

Comment: That coefficient is a $866$ digit number $\approx 2.50664193692 \times 10^{865}$. If one compute the coefficient $x^{n-1}$ from $\prod_{k=1}^{n^2} (x+k)$, there doesn't seem to be any pattern of the coefficient at all. I've strong doubt this can be done by hand.

Comment: It does not say in the question that the answer needs to be given as a decimal number. See Johns comment.

Comment: I wanted to paste the coefficient I calculated, it is but $\color{orange}{\text{too long by 266 characters}}$. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply together all the terms, you'll get a sum. Think of each term in this sum as a $400$ letter long word, where the $j$th letter is either an $x$ or the number $j$ (for $1\leq j \leq 400)$.
You can of course simplify this expression into the form of $l \cdot x^k$ where k and l is some numbers.

Now, for example the only way to get $x^{400}$ in this sum is to choose $x$ from each pair of parentheses to get the $xx...xx$, a $400$ letter long word.

So how can you get a word which simplifies into the form of $l\cdot x^{19}$?
Well if you choose $x$ from exactly $19$ terms and choose the numbers from the other $400-19$, you'll get such a term.
And it's not hard to see that this is the only way to do so.

So what's going to be the coefficient?
If you add up the coefficients of all the appropriate terms from the sum(ie. of the form $l\cdot x^{19})$, then you get the following:
with $S=\{1,...,400\}$

$a_{19} = \sum_{I \subseteq S \text{ and } |I| = 19} \prod_{i \in S \setminus I}(i)$
If you multiply together all the terms, you'll get a sum. Think of each term in this sum as a $400$ letter long word, where the $j$th letter is either an $x$ or the number $j$ (for $1\leq j \leq 400)$.
You can of course simplify this expression into the form of $l \cdot x^k$ where k and l is some numbers.

Now, for example the only way to get $x^{400}$ in this sum is to choose $x$ from each pair of parentheses to get the $xx...xx$, a $400$ letter long word.

So how can you get a word which simplifies into the form of $l\cdot x^{19}$?
Well if you choose $x$ from exactly $19$ terms and choose the numbers from the other $400-19$, you'll get such a term.
And it's not hard to see that this is the only way to do so.

So what's going to be the coefficient?
If you add up the coefficients of all the appropriate terms from the sum(ie. of the form $l\cdot x^{19})$, then you get the following:
with $S=\{1,...,400\}$

$a_{19} = \sum_{I \subseteq S \text{ and } |I| = 19} \prod_{i \in S \setminus I}(i)$

Also note that all the numbers in this sum are nonnegative and the tiniest one is $381!$

So the coefficient is at least - and in fact much more, than - $\binom{400}{19}381!$, therefore for all purposes it is incomputable by hand.

Comment: Is that sum feasible to find just by hand?

Comment: Yes, that much is clear, but since there are $\binom{400}{19}=146370655310808227709860948713600$ of these, i.e. far more than a computer could currently compute within a lifetime, something more needs to be said if we are to actually calculate the result.

Comment: Note that you can easily compute the number using a computer, polynomial multiplication is nothing else than discrete convolution. I was able to determine the coefficient (using floating points arithmetic due to the size) in Matlab quite quickly (fraction of a second) using repeated convolution.

Comment: @flawr: That's more a comment on the question than on this answer, since the number of operations required to do that is far less than the number required to compute the sum in this answer.

Comment: @flawr I meant no one could calculate this during a math contest, -assuming no computers are allowed. Thank you for the clarification, I've edited my answer to be more clear.