# What are the coefficients of the polynomial expansion of binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Considering the binomial coefficient:
$$
    {{x}\choose{k} } = \frac{x(x-1)...(x-k+1)}{k!}
$$
It is clear that it could be written as a polynomial in $x$  but there are explicit computations of ${{x}\choose{k} }$ as a polynomial
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k a_{i,k}x^i
$$
i.e. it is possible to compute in general $a_{i,k}$?
Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: See "Relation with the roots of a monic univariate polynomial" section-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial

Comment: These are the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Definitions).

Comment: See also: [Coefficients of polynomial equation having integer roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281473) and [Find the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the expression $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots (x+400)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stirling number of the first kind $s(k, p) $ is defined as the coefficient of $x^p$ in the numerator of the polynomial you are asking about. Thus the full expansion is
$$\sum_p\frac{s(k, p)} {k!} x^p$$